# Android: canvas keeps alternating between previous and current drawing commands

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

So, I'm developing a game and I'm using Canvas with SurfaceHolder to update the screen every time an object is supposed to move. That much is working fine so far. Now, the problem happens when I want to stop drawing to the Canvas and just leave it as it is based on the last drawing commands.

So one way that I tried was to simply return from the function that I call when drawing when the end condition is met. However, when I do this, the canvas starts rapidly alternating between the commands sent right when the condition was met and the commands sent one iteration before. I have no idea how or why this is happening since the drawing function is not executing any of its draw commands after the condition is met. Can anyone explain how the canvas can keep refreshing itself when it doesn't get any draw commands?

The code in the thread for locking and unlocking is pretty simple:

```
    public void run() {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = sh.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized(sh) {
                drawCan(c);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if(c!=null) {
                sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the drawCan function is structured like this:

```
public void drawCan(Canvas c) {
    /* Check if user's health is greater than 0. Don't draw anything if it is less */
    if(userHealth<=0) {
        return;
    }
    /* Drawing commands - drawRect(), drawBitmap(), etc are run here */
}
```

Now normally, this runs fine. But when the userHealth condition is met, the Canvas constantly alternates between the last commands sent and the commands right before that. I know that the draw functions are not being called because I used Log.d() in that area of the code and no messages appeared on LogCat after the condition was met. Can someone explain why this is happening and what the solution would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Canvas` is double- or triple- buffered and not erased between frames.  When you call lock/unlock, you're switching between previously-rendered buffers.

If you move your `if(userHealth<=0)` test into `run()` and use it to avoid calling lock/unlock, you should get the desired effect.

For a much longer explanation about what's going on, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838523/annoying-lags-stutters-in-an-android-game/22387533#22387533).

**Update:** I realized today that I'd omitted a detail (from the answer and ensuing comments).  It doesn't change the answer but it may be useful to know.

The `lockCanvas()` method takes an optional "dirty" rect that allows you to do partial updates.  If you use this, and `Surface` is able to keep track of the "front" buffer you just rendered, the system will copy the non-dirty contents of the front buffer to the back buffer as part of locking the `Surface` (see `copyBlt()` in [Surface.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/libs/gui/Surface.cpp)).

The system doesn't guarantee that this will work, which is why the "dirty" rect is an in-out parameter.  If the front buffer isn't available to copy from, the lock method will just expand the dirty rect to cover the entire screen.  In either case, your app is responsible for updating every pixel in the "dirty" rect; if you don't, you get the effects you observed.

This does mean that the `Surface` is explicitly trying to be double-buffered when used with a `Canvas`, which would explain why you're seeing two frames alternating rather than three even though `SurfaceView` is generally triple-buffered.  (Which is the thing that has been nagging at me since I wrote this up.)  It's also possible to be double-buffered if you're just not generating frames fast enough to require triple-buffering.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. So basically, when I make draw commands on the locked canvas, the rendered frames are buffered in a sort of stack. Those buffered frames are then drawn to the screen in order. If nothing new is being added, the existing renderings are just re-written repeatedly to the screen. Is this correct?

Comment: Essentially.  "Lock" grabs the next free buffer, with all of its previous contents; "unlock" sends that buffer to the compositor for display, whether or not you actually drew on it.  There's no guarantee of ordering, so even if there are 10 buffers in the queue you might just flip between two of them.  If your app doesn't do lock/unlock, the compositor will just keep displaying whatever buffer it received last.

Comment: ok, I think I understand the concept now. I'll try it out and see what happens.

Comment: ok, it seems to be working now. I used a different method but I understand the concept now. Thanks.